# Not authorized to access topics inside Event Hub namespace

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

I have Event Hub Namespace with two Event Hubs (`event-hub` and `event-hub-2`). To establish connection I use Kafka - of course namespace is with Standard Tier. When I try to connect to the second EH (`event-hub-2` as a Kafka Topic, Connection String as a Kafka Password) I got following stacktrace:

```scala
2021-06-17T15:56:04.976Z -  WARN: [NetworkClient] [Consumer clientId=consumer-$Default-1, groupId=$Default] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 11 : {event-hub=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED}
2021-06-17T15:56:04.980Z - ERROR: [Metadata] [Consumer clientId=consumer-$Default-1, groupId=$Default] Topic authorization failed for topics [event-hub]
2021-06-17T15:56:05.007Z - ERROR: [KafkaConsumerActor] [9e1ad] Exception when polling from consumer, stopping actor: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [event-hub]
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [event-hub]
```

My question is: WHY I could got this kind of stacktrace when I didn't even try to connect to topic/EH from stacktrace? It's a weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the same consumer group in both scenarios,  your consumer needs read access to all topics used in the consumer group, try changing the group.id and test again.

Comment: After few hours I tried to connect with my previous solution, and what is more weird, it started to work ;O Thanks @Ran Lupovich for help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem came back when I connect my subscribers to Event Hubs simultaneously. Just like Ran said, connecting to different consumer groups resolved problem. Many thanks!